# How to simulate adc with avr simulator 2?

Tags: avr, simulation

I would like to know is there a way to simulate (without involving real hardware) analogue input for the ADC pin with stimuli file in avr simulator 2?

I've failed simulating it in Proteus and in my opinion it does not provide enough flexibility and most important speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

As per the [documentation](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/simulator/simulator.section.okd_gud_lc.html):

> The simulator is not a complete model of the device. While digital logic is simulated cycle-accurately, **all analog periphery is presently lacking**

The simulations are not real simulations of hardware, they simulate the behaviour of the digital circuitry. There is no implementation of the analogue functionality in the simulations.

Comment: Is there any other method I can use to simulate ADC logic?